# Como descobrir se o ano é bissexto em PHP?

Tags: php, data

Como faço para saber se o ano atual é um ano bissexto em PHP?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Uma outra forma é usar a função [`date`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.date.php) com o parâmetro `L` que retorna `1` se está em ano bissexto, `0` caso contrário.

Exemplo para ano atual:

```
echo date('L');
```

Para um ano específico:

```
$ano = 2007;
$bissexto= date('L', mktime(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, $ano));
echo $ano . ' ' . ($bissexto? 'é' : 'não é') . ' um ano bissexto.';
```

Veja funcionando no [**ideone**](https://ideone.com/4Rm2gP).

Comment: +1. Ontem eu converti um sistema velho de calendário feito em DateTime usando date() + timestamp, e o código ficou com 60% do tamanho original, e muito mais simples de ler. E tenho guardado a informação do dia como ( time() ou timestamp / 86400 ) pra simplificar no DB quando não há uso de horas (só não pode esquecer do date('Z') pra ajustar o timezone).

Answer (score 20):

Outra forma de saber se o ano é bissexto, é saber a quantia de dias de fevereiro, isso pode ser feito com o argumento `t` da função `date()`

```
 echo  date('t', strtotime('2016-02-01')); //29
```

Comment: Parabéns, brilhante, senhor. `such little code, wow the best`.

Comment: Muito bom, realmente é sempre bom lembrar dos parâmetros do `date` !! Obrigado!

Comment: É mesmo @GuilhermeNascimento. Acho que tem uma galera que não sabe disso :D

Comment: Estou com muita vontade de editar a resposta e adicionar todos parametros :D

Answer (score 16):

Uma solução alternativa é usar uma função nativa do PHP que é própria pra isto, o [`cal_days_in_month`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.cal-days-in-month.php)

Exemplos:

```
<?php
//2015 não é bisexto
$result = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, 2, 2015) === 29;
var_dump($result);

//2016 é bisexto
$result = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, 2, 2016) === 29;
var_dump($result);
```

Exemplo online: https://ideone.com/JgvjPQ

Uma função simples:

```
function isLeapYear($year = NULL) {
     $year = is_numeric($year) ? $year : date('Y');
     return cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, 2, $year) === 29;
}
```

Usando:

```
var_dump(isLeapYear());//Ano atual
var_dump(isLeapYear(2015));//Ano 2015
var_dump(isLeapYear(2016));//Ano 2016
var_dump(isLeapYear(2017));//Ano 2017
```

Online: https://ideone.com/6ptj5P

Comment: Essa eu não conhecia, legal :D +1

Answer (score 15):

Para fazer tal operação você pode utilizar duas maneiras, mas as duas levam a um mesmo método: Verificar se fevereiro termina com o dia 29.

**Strtotime e date**

```
(date('d', strtotime('last day of february this year')) === '29')
```

**Objeto DateTime**

```
(new DateTime('last day of february this year'))->format('d') === '29')
```

Essa solução é tão simples, que alguns me questionaram no chat se eu estava brincando. 
Para ficar convincente, fiz um exemplo no IDEONE:

https://ideone.com/XzP6jK

É possível utilizar essa sintaxe para qualquer ano. Se desejar verificar outro ano, poderia ser trocado o trecho `this year` para `2018` ou `next year` por exemplo.

Comment: `last day of february this year` :D PHP "falante" hehehe +1

Answer (score 7):

Podemos usar a regra do [calendário gregoriano](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gregorian_calendar), no qual um ano bissexto segue as seguintes regras:

- se não for divisível por 4, não é bissexto
- se for divisível por 4:

  - se for divisível por 100, só é bissexto se também for divisível por 400
  - se não for divisível por 100, é bissexto

Então ficaria assim:

```
$year = date('Y');
if (($year % 4 == 0) && ($year % 100 != 0 || $year %400 == 0)) {
    echo "$year é bissexto";
} else {
    echo "$year não é bissexto";
}
```

---

**Atenção**: este método difere de algumas respostas, dependendo do ano. Por exemplo, comparando com o método de pegar o último dia de fevereiro:

```
for ($year = 1; $year < 10100; $year++) {
    $x = ($year % 4 == 0) && ($year % 100 != 0 || $year %400 == 0);
    $y = date('d', strtotime('last day of february '. $year)) === '29';
    if ($x != $y) {
        echo "$year, $x, $y\n";
    }
}
```

Isso dá diferença para anos menores que 1000 e maiores que 10000.

Fazendo o mesmo teste acima com `cal_days_in_month` em vez de `strtotime`, os resultados não diferem. E com `mktime`, só deu diferença no ano 100.

---

Vale lembrar que esta regra vale para o Calendário Gregoriano, que é o que usamos atualmente na maior parte do mundo. Então para efeitos práticos podemos considerar o código acima e os das demais respostas.

Mas se formos considerar outros calendários, aí a regra muda. Por exemplo, no [Calendário Juliano](https://www.timeanddate.com/calendar/julian-calendar.html), a cada 4 anos ocorre um ano bissexto, então a forma de calcular seria simplesmente `if ($year % 4 == 0) { bissexto }`.

E as coisas podem se complicar ainda mais se quisermos considerar qual calendário estava sendo usado, dependendo do ano.

Oficialmente o Calendário Gregoriano foi decretado em 1582. Porém, [cada lugar do mundo o adotou em um data diferente](https://www.timeanddate.com/calendar/julian-gregorian-switch.html), então se for para ser preciso mesmo, você precisaria considerar não somente **quando**, mas também **onde**, para saber qual regra aplicar (só para citar alguns exemplos, a França fez a mudança em 1582, enquanto a Turquia só mudou em 1926). Claro que se você só vai trabalhar com datas atuais, isso não é uma preocupação.

E claro, [ainda há outros calendários usados atualmente, com regras completamente diferentes](https://www.timeanddate.com/date/leap-year-in-other-calendars.html): o Calendário Judaico define 7 anos bissextos a cada intervalo de 19 anos ([veja a regra do cálculo aqui](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hebrew_calendar#Leap_years)), o [Calendário Persa](https://www.timeanddate.com/date/iran-leap-year.html) não usa uma regra matemática e baseia-se na ocorrência dos equinócios, etc.

Mas creio que a pergunta se refere - implicitamente - ao Calendário Gregoriano, então esta parte da resposta fica mais como curiosidade.

Answer (score 0):

Em uma linha, é possível verificar formatando a data com 'L' (leap year, em inglês)

```
echo (date('L', strtotime("$ano-01-01")) ? 'SIM' : 'NÃO');
```

Onde `$ano` é o ano que você quer testar.

Ver mais parâmetros [aqui](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/date-format-function-in-php)