# Identificar quantos dias tem o mês (28, 29, 30, 31)

Tags: php

Existe alguma **função nativa** que identifique **quantos dias tem o mês**?

**Exemplo:**

Passo o **valor**: `2018-08`, então o **retorno** seria: `31`.

```
$dias = funcao('2018-08');
echo $dias; // resultado: 31
```

---

**Caso não** exista função nativa, **como poderia fazer**?

---

*Antes que perguntem: tem o ano bissexto (fevereiro com 29).*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Existe sim uma função nativa do php para isso, ela é [cal_days_in_month](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.cal-days-in-month.php).

Esta função irá retornar o número de dias em um month do year para o calendar especificado.

```
int cal_days_in_month ( int $calendar , int $month , int $year )
```

**Onde:**

- calendar: Calendário para usar no cálculo
- month: Mês a ser selecionado no calendário
- year: Ano no selecionado calendário

**Exemplo:**

```
<?php
    $dias = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, 8, 2018); // 31
    echo "Existem ".$dias." dias em Agosto de 2018";
?>
```

Answer (score 6):

Como eu respondi em https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/109277/3635 eu diria que a melhor forma de fazer isto é usando uma função nativa criada para isto mesmo:

```
echo cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, 8, 2018);
```

Answer (score 4):

```
 $funcao = new DateTime("2018-08");

 $numDias = $funcao->format('t');
```

[date](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.date.php) - string do parâmetro format

```
 format  |   Descrição                      |  Retorno
 ------------------------------------------------------
 t       |   Número de dias de um dado mês  | 28 até 31
```

[**exemplo - ideone**](https://ideone.com/ZtVHRS)

Answer (score -2):

Podes usar `$days = date("t");`

Retorna numero de dias do mês atual.

[Manual Date PHP](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.date.php)

Comment: A sugestão é boa, mas para pegar o mês atual, para pegar de outro mês e ano ai teria que usar `strtotime` o que complica, mas você pode adaptar como uma função.