# Como converter o valor informado pelo header If-Modified-Since em uma data (e vice-versa)?

Tags: php, http, datetime, http-headers

O header [`If-Modified-Since`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/If-Modified-Since) apresenta o seguinte formato de retorno:

```
Wed, 21 Oct 2015 07:28:00 GMT
```

Eu preciso comparar essa data que vem nesse item do header com a data de criação de um arquivo no meu servidor, através da função `filemtime($arquivo)`.

Eu quero fazer duas coisas:

- Transformar o `If-Modified-Since` em uma data válida do PHP para compará-lo com a data retornada em `filemtime`.
- Transformar o retorno de `filemtime` numa data no formato igual ao do header `If-Modified-Since`, para enviar como header `Last-Modified` ao negavador.

Sendo assim, a pergunta é:

- Existe algum padrão no PHP para formatar a data igual a desse header? E se tem um padrão, esse formato de data tem um nome?

Answer (score 2):

Basta usar o formato `'D, d M Y H:i:s T'` (veja a descrição de cada campo na [documentação](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php#refsect1-datetime.createfromformat-parameters)).

Para transformar a string em data, use `date_create_from_format`, e a partir da data retornada por esta função, use `getTimestamp` para poder comparar com o timestamp retornado por `filemtime`:

```
$data = date_create_from_format('D, d M Y H:i:s T', 'Wed, 21 Oct 2015 07:28:00 GMT');
if ($data && $data->getTimestamp() > filemtime('arquivo')) {
    etc...
}
```

---

Já para converter o retorno de `filemtime` para o formato em questão, use [`gmdate`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gmdate.php), que é similar à `date`, porém força que a data retornada esteja em GMT (com `date` não funciona, porque ele retorna `UTC` em vez de `GMT`). Veja a diferença:

```
// testando com um arquivo modificado hoje
echo gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s T', filemtime('arquivo')); // Wed, 10 Feb 2021 14:24:23 GMT
echo date('D, d M Y H:i:s T', filemtime('arquivo'));   // Wed, 10 Feb 2021 14:24:23 UTC
```

---

Outra alternativa é usar a [constante `DateTimeInterface::RFC7231`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetimeinterface.php#datetime.constants.rfc7231) como formato, que por colocar explicitamente "GMT" no final, funciona tanto com `date` quanto com `gmdate`:

```
$format = DateTimeInterface::RFC7231;
$data = date_create_from_format($format, 'Wed, 21 Oct 2015 07:28:00 GMT');
// usar $data, etc

echo gmdate($format, filemtime('arquivo')); // Wed, 10 Feb 2021 14:24:23 GMT
echo date($format, filemtime('arquivo'));   // Wed, 10 Feb 2021 14:24:23 GMT
```

---

#### Indo um pouco além...

Como a pergunta fala sobre o "valor do *header* `If-Modified-Since`", acho que vale a pena se aprofundar um pouco mais.

Se consultarmos a RFC 7232 (HTTP Conditional Requests), veremos que [o *header* `If-Modified-Since` é definido como](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7232#section-3.3):

```
 If-Modified-Since = HTTP-date

An example of the field is:

 If-Modified-Since: Sat, 29 Oct 1994 19:43:31 GMT
```

E a [definição de `HTTP-date` está na RFC 7231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-7.1.1.1) (tradução e ênfases minhas):

> Antes de 1995, havia 3 formatos diferentes usados pelos servidores para envio de timestamps. Por motivos de compatibilidade com implementações antigas, todos os 3 são definidos aqui. O **formato preferencial** é ... um *subset* do especificado na [RFC5322](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322#section-3.3):
>
> ```
> HTTP-date    = IMF-fixdate / obs-date
> ```
>
> Um exemplo do **formato preferencial**:
>
> ```
> Sun, 06 Nov 1994 08:49:37 GMT    ; IMF-fixdate
> ```
>
> Exemplos dos formatos **obsoletos**:
>
> ```
> Sunday, 06-Nov-94 08:49:37 GMT   ; obsolete RFC 850 format
> Sun Nov  6 08:49:37 1994         ; ANSI C's asctime() format
> ```

Ou seja, atualmente, deve-se dar preferência ao formato citado na pergunta (e que é definido na [RFC5322](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322#section-3.3)). Mas a RFC 7321 também cita que "*A recipient that parses a timestamp value in an HTTP header field **MUST accept all three HTTP-date formats***" (ou seja, mesmo que os 2 últimos formatos estejam obsoletos, ainda devem ser aceitos).

Sendo assim, uma alternativa para aceitar os 3 formatos é tentar um a um, até que seja possível fazer o *parsing* (ou até que todos falhem):

```
function parse($headerValue) {
    // formatos (dando preferência para o não-obsoleto)
    $formatos = [ DateTimeInterface::RFC7231, DateTimeInterface::RFC850, 'D M d H:i:s Y' ];
    foreach ($formatos as $formato) {
        $data = date_create_from_format($formato, $headerValue);
        if ($data) return $data;
    }
    return FALSE;
}

$formato_saida = DateTimeInterface::RFC7231;
$values = [ 'Wed, 21 Oct 2015 07:28:00 GMT', 'Sunday, 06-Nov-94 08:49:37 GMT', 'Sun Nov  6 08:49:37 1994' ];
foreach ($values as $val) {
    $data = parse($val);
    if ($data) {
        if ($data->getTimestamp() > filemtime('arquivo')) {
            // etc...
        }
        $saida = gmdate($formato_saida, $data->getTimestamp());
        echo "$val -> $saida\n";
    } else {
        echo "$val -> data inválida\n";
    }
}
```

Para fazer o *parsing*, dei preferência para o formato... preferencial indicado na RFC, e depois eu tento os obsoletos. Repare que o segundo formato é [`RFC850`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetimeinterface.php#datetime.constants.rfc850) (que lê o ano com 2 dígitos), em vez do [`COOKIE`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetimeinterface.php#datetime.constants.cookie) (que é quase igual, só que ele tenta ler o ano com 4 dígitos e `94` é interpretado como o ano 94 em vez de 1994). E para o terceiro formato, não achei uma constante pré-definida que servisse, então montei o formato manualmente mesmo.

Já para formatar a saída, eu usei o `RFC7231`, que coloca sempre "GMT" no final (os demais colocam outros valores, como "UTC" ou "+00:00"). Optei por usar esse formato, porque é o único que a RFC define como não sendo obsoleto (ou seja, para receber eu aceito qualquer formato, mas na hora de enviar, uso o "preferencial" não-obsoleto). A saída do código acima é:

```
Wed, 21 Oct 2015 07:28:00 GMT -> Wed, 21 Oct 2015 07:28:00 GMT
Sunday, 06-Nov-94 08:49:37 GMT -> Sun, 06 Nov 1994 08:49:37 GMT
Sun Nov  6 08:49:37 1994 -> Sun, 06 Nov 1994 08:49:37 GMT
```

---

#### Uma alternativa mais simples

As opções acima são para o caso de você, além da comparação com `filemtime`, também precisar manipular a data de outras maneiras (já que `date_create_from_format` retorna um `DateTime`).

Mas se você só quer o valor do timestamp para poder comparar com o retorno de `filemtime`, pode usar `strtotime`, que reconhece os 3 formatos definidos na RFC:

```
$formato_saida = DateTimeInterface::RFC7231;
$values = [ 'Wed, 21 Oct 2015 07:28:00 GMT', 'Sunday, 06-Nov-94 08:49:37 GMT', 'Sun Nov  6 08:49:37 1994' ];
foreach ($values as $val) {
    $timestamp = strtotime($val);
    if ($timestamp === FALSE) {
        echo "$val -> data inválida\n";
    } else {
        // comparação direta
        if ($timestamp > filemtime('arquivo')) {
            // etc...
        }

        // formatar para o formato preferencial não-obsoleto
        $saida = gmdate($formato_saida, $timestamp);
        echo "$val -> $saida\n";
    }
}
```

A diferença, claro, é que `strtotime` aceita vários outros formatos (alguns até meio "esotéricos", [como `'last day of february this year'`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/109258/112052)), então depende do quão rígido você quer ser: se quer aceitar **somente** os 3 formatos indicados pela RFC, use a função `parse` definida acima (que só aceita especificamente aqueles formatos).

Mas se a entrada é controlada (por exemplo, você garante que a data é obtida do *header* - que nesse caso, estará disponível em `$_SERVER['HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE']`) e que não estará em um formato fora do padrão, usar `strtotime` simplifica as coisas.

---

Para mais detalhes, veja ["*Handling If-modified-since header in a PHP-script*"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10847157).

Comment: Um detalhe, se o valor recebido pelo header por acaso for inválido o `DateTime::createFromFormat` (procedural: date_create_from_format) vai retornar `FALSE`, então seria bom fazer o IF dessa forma: `if ($data && $data->getTimestamp() > filemtime('arquivo')) {`

Answer (score 2):

Na verdade para enviar o `Last-Modified` não precisa do `If-Modified-Since`, o `If-Modified-Since` já é **consequência** do `Last-Modified`, então se a pretensão é de enviar apenas o `filemtime($arquivo)` como `Last-Modified` para a resposta HTTP, bastaria um `gmdate` com os parametros na ordem correta, pois o `filemtime` já trabalha com Unix time, algo como:

```
$modified = filemtime(<arquivo>);

header('Last-Modified: ' . gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', $modified) . ' GMT');
```

Você pode escapar o GMT com `\G\M\T` ou usar o `T`, mas é irrelevante, o valor esperado deve ser GMT mesmo, faça como achar mais agradável.

O `If-Modified-Since` sendo **consequência** do último `Last-Modified` será usado se precisar comparar o que tem no servidor com o que tem no cliente, então é por isso que nas próximas requisições ao mesmo endereço poderá trabalhar esse valor, comparando você poderá diminuir a carga de downloads, usando o código 304:

```
$modified = filemtime(<arquivo>);

if (<If-Modified-Since> >= $modified) {
    http_response_code(304);
    exit;
}

header('Last-Modified: ' . gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', $modified) . ' GMT');

readfile(<arquivo>);
```

Nesse pseudocódigo enviamos o arquivo para a resposta HTTP somente se o arquivo tiver sido modificado, caso contrário o navegador (ou outro sistema de cliente que trabalhe com HTTP) deve entender que nada mudou e portanto deverá reaproveitar o cache existente.

É possível também trabalhar em conjunto com `E-tag` ou usar apenas `E-tag`, não necessariamente é obrigado a trabalhar com ambos, a ideia do `E-tag` é ter um meio de confirmar se não houve mesmo modificação, ele pode conter a versão ou uma "hash" (valor ASCII), existe o indicado do E-tag se está usando um **validador fraco** ou **não**, mas tudo isso é outra história e vai muito além do perguntando.

Voltando ao foco. Só se realmente o objetivo é usar o `304 Not Modified` que o código a seguir será útil:

```
$data = date_create_from_format('D, d M Y H:i:s T', <If-Modified-Since>);

if ($data && filemtime(<arquivo>) > $data->getTimestamp()) {
    etc...
}
```

O objetivo disso seria validar o valor enviado no header da requisição HTTP, já que headers de requisição HTTP podem ser manipulados, então uma ideia de implementação semi funcional seria:

```
$modified = filemtime($arquivo);

// Checa se o header foi enviado pelo cliente e então tenta fazer o parse
$data = isset($_SERVER['HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE']) ? date_create_from_format('D, d M Y H:i:s T', $_SERVER['HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE']) : null;

if ($data && $data->getTimestamp() >= $modified) {
    http_response_code(304);
    exit;
}

header('Last-Modified: ' . gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', $modified) . ' GMT');

readfile($arquivo);
```

Pela lógica tem que ser `>=` e não `>` porque se o arquivo não mudou os valores serão "iguais".

Essa implementação toda pode ser feita até mesmo em "frameworks" que tem interface própria de HTTP e prévalidar o header de requisição `If-Modified-Since` em algum tipo de middleware, ou talvez o próprio framework ou o servidor HTTP valide isso, mas não posso afirmar por todas tecnologias, só quero dizer que dependendo do cenário talvez a validação possa ser dispensável nesse ponto da execução se outra tecnologia já implementar.

Vale lembrar que no exemplo usei a função `readfile`, mas até aonde usei ela foi problemática com arquivos grandes, o ideal para arquivos grandes seria usar `fopen` + `flush`, mas isso é questão de otimização, que vai muito além do que é perguntando.